# Pork byproducts in different names

Tags: halal-haram, taharah, najis, self-purification

Assalamu 'alaikum,

I have a difficulty for keeping my body pure and sometimes I feel it is very hard to keep it like that. Because these days almost every product is related to some animal origin, such as leather,greases, food items, paints, etc. And I have no guarantee over those whether it is made from pork or not. So I feel it is very hard to avoid such things. And I had some kind of waswas also I think and I'm sure no one near me cares about these things. But I feel if I use such items  my prayer becomes invalid.
And I searched for a cure from these kind of things and I found these two hadeeths:

1:Everything is pure unless you are certain about it that it is otherwise.

2:Avoid those things which make you doubt.

So I dont know what I should do.

For example I found white greases are made from inedible lard (from pork)so what should I do because I'm a mechanical engineering student and a car enthusiast so how should I abstain from those things?

It is easy to abstain from food items that contains pork some times. But it's very hard to abstain to those items that indirectly contain pork such as greases for automobile,paints, etc.
I am suffering a lot about this issue.

> Can you please advice me what should I do?

May allah shower his blessings upon you and your family. 
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Salamu 'alaikum achi

It's permissible to work with as long as you cleanse yourself afterwards by performing wudu.

*Ibn al-Qayyim said:

Based on this principle, alcohol is impure, even though its origin is pure. If the reason for its being regarded as impure is no longer present, then it is to be regarded as pure. This is the basis of sharee’ah and the basis of reward and punishment.*

Rest assured with the help of Allah.

Source:

https://www.quora.com/Islam-forbids-eating-pork-but-does-it-also-forbid-handling-pork  (2nd and 3rd answer)

https://islamqa.info/en/97541